# How to generate a static call graph for Java?

Tags: java, call-graph

Does any of you know to to generate a static call graph for a java project? Or maybe you know a website or paper that describes an algorithm for generating such a graph. I'm currently reading the paper "Call Graph Construction in Object Oriented programming" but I would like to     have more ideas of such algorithms and I've been looking even in digital libraries and there aren't much information or relative papers besides this paper. At this point I will also consider any existing APIs that generate this call graph.

PS I've already looked for some relevant answers and as [Customizable static call graph for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147801/customizable-static-call-graph-for-eclipse) I would like to construct a static call graph.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161613/call-graph-of-the-whole-application.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4951517/120163